# use java stream to find count of each character in a string

Tags: java, java-stream

we have this string:  `String input1 = "abbccd";`

expected output: `ab2c2d`   (note: if count=1, it shouldn't show in output).

the following code outputs `a1,b2 c2 d2` on separate lines. Any suggestion to fix and improve?

```
input1.chars()
      .mapToObj(s -> Character.toLowerCase(Character.valueOf((char) s)))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .forEach(n -> {System.out.println(n.getKey()+""+n.getValue());});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the last `forEach` a `map` instead.

Instead of `n.getValue()` only add that part if `n.getValue` is not 1.

Then collect by joining.

At that point you will have a string you can print.

So, assuming we don't want to change your first part:

```
"abbccd".chars()
        .mapToObj(s -> Character.toLowerCase((char)s)) // notice here Character.valueOf was redundant, we're already dealing with a char
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(n -> n.getKey()+""+(n.getValue() == 1 ? "" : n.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Results in `ab2c2d`.

Comment: Might as well do `.mapToObj(s -> Character.toLowerCase((char) s))` too. No need to take the character value of a character.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, I only focused on the last part. But I'll make that change as well, while I'm at it.

Comment: `Collectors.joining("")` can just be `Collectors.joining()`

Comment: Your code breaks with most characters. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549578/642706) for an example of such failure, and for a solution. If you care to rework your Answer with code points, I'll gladly delete mine.

Comment: @BasilBourque right and noted. I won't change my answer because it still fits the given input. I upvoted yours, thought, in the hope it will surface to the top spot and be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the other two Answers both fail with most characters.

## Avoid legacy type `char`

The `char` type is legacy, essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most of the 144,697 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

See one Answer’s code break:

```java
String input = "abbccd";
String output =
        input
                .chars()
                .mapToObj( s -> Character.toLowerCase( ( char ) s ) ) // notice here Character.valueOf was redundant, we're already dealing with a char
                .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity() , LinkedHashMap :: new , Collectors.counting() ) )
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map( n -> n.getKey() + "" + ( n.getValue() == 1 ? "" : n.getValue() ) )
                .collect( Collectors.joining() );

System.out.println( "output = " + output );
```

> output = ?2?2ab2c2d

## Code point

Use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead, when working with individual characters. A code point is the number permanently assigned to each character in Unicode. They range from zero to just over a million.

You will find code point related method scattered around the Java classes. These include `String`, `StringBuilder`, `Character`, etc.

The `String#codePoints` method returns an `IntStream` of code points, the code point number for each character in the string.

Here is a re-worked version of the clever code from [Answer by Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73547306/642706). Kudos to him, as I could not have come up with that approach.

```java
String input = "abbccd";
String output =
        input
                .codePoints()
                .map( Character :: toLowerCase )
                .mapToObj( codePoint -> Character.toString( codePoint ) )
                .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity() , LinkedHashMap :: new , Collectors.counting() ) )
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map( n -> n.getKey() + "" + ( n.getValue() == 1 ? "" : n.getValue() ) )
                .collect( Collectors.joining() );
System.out.println( "output = " + output );
```

> output = 2ab2c2d

Comment: This solution still is incomplete. First, it still doesn’t handle all *characters*. A character can span multiple code points. E.g., try `"️‍️‍"`. Then, mapping to lowercase is not the handling all characters for insensitive matching. In fact, it’s not even handling the (case sensitive) equality for all characters.